# Highcharts JS - Stacked Column: each column filled

Tags: highcharts, stacked

How do you set up a stacked column chart so that the bottom series represents the data values, and the top series is only there to fill in the empty space?

See attached image for reference:

[image]

Comment: You need to tell that story here because I have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you checked out the JPG you it will become obvious.  Regardless, I'll give it my best shot.  Each column has a value.  Beyond that value I'd like the rest of the column 'coloured' with a default colour.  That simple really.

Comment: Here's one way to do it programmatically:  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/Zf8C7/  establish your data series, establish the max to fill to, loop through and build second series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so basically you need 2 graphs

1. percentage stacked column

   `plotOptions: {
       column: { 
           stacking: 'percent'
       }
   }`

here is a worked out example http://jsfiddle.net/kolliparavamsikrishna/8xGA2/
2. combination of percentage stacked column and error bar.
here is a worked out example http://jsfiddle.net/kolliparavamsikrishna/TfG5P/

Comment: Why would it require 2 graphs? (and your example isn't 2 graphs either...?)  Additionally, a percent stack only works well if you are actually measuring the percentages.  Otherwise you have to do a lot of work to make your axis labels and tooltips display the right info.

Comment: the example asker provided looks like the person is looking for 2 graphs

Comment: Just what I was looking for.  Thanks!  Glad you took a look at the image.  Explains my request far better than my lame note.